# Back up phonebook list along with all data I used before factory reset

Tags: restore

I'm using Karbonn A11 Android phone. One of my friends tried to guess my pattern and unfortunately he locked my phone. I want my phonebook list back before factory restore. Please suggest to me how could I get back my data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sync enabled in your mobile, then your phone book list will be automatically stored in your Google account. Go to "contacts.google.com" to find your contacts.

Else If you have USB Debugging enabled in your phone, you can follow this [link](http://en.miui.com/thread-5684-1-1.html) to unlock your phone.